# How do I enable shipping.log for debugging in Magento 2.3.1?

Tags: magento-2.3

I was able to access the shipping.log in magento 2.3.0 but since upgrading to 2.3.1 the log no longer exists under /var/log/

Does anyone know where to find this or how to activate the shipping logs?

I've set:
Stores > Configuration > Sales > Shipping Methods > Debug to true

I've also ran the following CLI commands:
bin/magento setup:config:set --enable-debug-logging=true
bin/magento cache:flush

I expect to see the shipping.log file located in /var/log/shipping.log

Answer (score 0):

Whoops sorry, I was looking in /var/log instead of magento-base-dir/var/log